# oci_pconnect error when ran in windows task scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, cmd

I'm trying to run a script that imports data from an Oracle table into a Mysql table. I'm using oci_pconnect to connect to Oracle. Everything is running fine when the script is executed in the browser but i'm getting the following error when the script is run in cmd under Windows

```
Fatal Error: Call to undefined function oci_pconnect()
```

I'm calling the php script in cmd by the following code

```
@echo off
php C:\wamp\www\somefile.php
echo Done!
pause > nul
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having this error, just go to php.ini located in your PHP folder and uncomment the line of the oci function in the extensions section:

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
```

problem solved!